# Cómo establecer el valor para el área de texto (textarea) en CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, formularios, validación, codeigniter-3

El area de texto (textarea) para mi validación en codeigniter no mantiene los datos colocados cuando se da error de validación. ¿Cual es la forma correcta?

controlador

```
 $mensaje = $this->input->post('mensaje');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('mensaje','Mensaje',    'required|min_length[3]|alpha|trim|xss_clean');
```

vista

```
<textarea class="mayuscula"  rows="04" cols="10" id="mensaje" name="mensaje"  style="margin-top:08px; width:80%"  required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+{1,50}" title="Se necesita un mensaje o requerimiento minimo dos letras"  autofocus="autofocus" value="<?php echo form_textarea ('mensaje'); ?>"/></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El tag `<textarea>` no tiene una propiedad value, si quieres poner un valor por defecto puedes hacer algo asi:

```
<textarea name="mensaje"> 
      <?php echo set_value('mensaje'); ?> 
</textarea>
```

Ademas para llenar de nuevo los datos del textarea debes usar

```
set_value($field[, $default = ''[, $html_escape = TRUE]]);
```

el parametro requerido es `$field`.

Con `form_textarea ('mensaje')` lo que estas haciendo es abrir un textarea nuevamente, deberías leer un poco mas la documentación de codeigniter.

Comment: Juan estoy usando el `<textarea name="description"> 
      <?php echo set_value('mensaje'); ?> 
</textarea>` igual que uso para todos los campos pero es el unico que no me mantiene los valos ingresados no entendi el codigo `set_value($field[, $default = ''[, $html_escape = TRUE]]);`

Comment: Perdon en description es mensaje, ahora lo edito. set_value($field[, $default = ''[, $html_escape = TRUE]]); quiere decir que set_value(), recibe 3 parametros, $field es el nombre del campo del formulario, $default es el valor por defecto que quieres ponerle al ese input, $html_escape, es para escapar valores html.

Comment: Juan en efecto estoy colocando `<textarea name="mensaje"> <?php echo set_value('mensaje'); ?>`  </textarea> pero no me lo toma lo que no entiendo es donde debo y como colocar el `set_value($field[, $default = ''[, $html_escape = TRUE]]);`  para que me mantenga los datos luego de la validacion.

Comment: Intenta colocando un valor por defecto, en set_value() para ver si esta regresando algo despues de la validacion, por ejemplo `set_value('mensaje','Valor por defecto');`

Comment: Juan coloque set_value('mensaje','hello');  y no me toma nada, consulte la guia de codeingniter y no menciona nada sobre este caso en particular.

Comment: Juan lo coloque de esta forma y funciono  `<textarea cols="50" rows="6" name="mensaje" id="mensaje" <?php echo set_value('mensaje'); ?></textarea><a ><?php  echo form_error('mensaje') ?></a>`

Comment: Y en los demas inputs si te funciona??